# Generar un "delay" de un dibujo en processing

Tags: processing

estoy trabajando sobre una especie de "geogebra" en el que tengo ejes cartesianos y yo apretando distintos botones genero una función distinta como por ejemplo un sen(x) o x^2 , y modifico el rango de las x con unas barras (sliderM y sliderM2), ya logre eso pero me piden ademas que una vez que muevo las barras, la funcion se tiene que ir dibujando lentamente hasta llegar al rango que seleccione en vez de que sea inmediato, pero no logro hacer eso, aca hay una parte de una de las funciones a la que deberia agregarle delay:

````
   
float x1 = 390;
float y1 = 200;
  if(boton1==true){
  for(float a=sliderM2-450; a<=sliderM-450; a=a+0.001){
   float x = x1+ 20*a;
   float y= (-20*pow(a,2))+y1;
   strokeWeight(2);
   stroke (255,0,0);
  if(y>0 && y<=400){
   
   point(x,y);
  
    }
   
 }```
````

Comment: Ya buscaste el equivalente de un `.sleep()`??

Comment: no, lei que se podia hacer con millis(), pero no pude llegar a nada, soy nuevo con processing, como seria sleep?